# Assignment with C# to apply discount. I'm using if-else

Tags: c#

My assignment is:

> Each item sold is $99.
>
> You get no discount selling under 10, so 1-9.
>
> You get a 5% discount selling 10-19.
>
> You get a 10% discount selling 20+.

When I put 1-9 numbers in my textbox, it doesn't apply the discount which is good. When I put 10-19, it applies the 5% off discount. But when I put 20 or any numbers higher, it still applies the 5% off discount and not a 10% discount.

My code:

```
double dblQuantitySold;
double dblAmountTotalDue;
double dblPrice = 99;

//Acquire the math.
dblQuantitySold = double.Parse(txtQuantity.Text);
dblAmountTotalDue = dblQuantitySold * dblPrice;

//Create the solution for your if-else statement.
if (dblQuantitySold >= 10)
{
    dblAmountTotalDue -= dblQuantitySold * dblPrice * 0.05;
    MessageBox.Show("A 5% discount will be given because 10 or more has been sold.");
}
else if (dblQuantitySold >= 20)
{
    dblAmountTotalDue -= dblQuantitySold * dblPrice * 0.10;
    MessageBox.Show("A 10% discount will be given because 20 or more has been sold.");
}

//Display the results.
lblAmountDueTotal.Text = dblAmountTotalDue.ToString("C");
```

Comment: Homework done, now time for the pub

Comment: Not sure why this homework question was down-voted.   Eric had made a programming attempt and also describes the expected and observed behavior afterall

Comment: @Eric - You should be using `decimal` instead of `double` for financial calculations - `double` is for scientific calcs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have the `if` statements in the wrong order. You first check if the item is greater than or equal to 10, which includes all values greater than 20. Just put the check for `>=20` first:

```
if (dblQuantitySold >= 20)
{
    dblAmountTotalDue -= dblQuantitySold * dblPrice * 0.10;
    MessageBox.Show("A 10% discount will be given because 20 or more has been sold.");
}
else if (dblQuantitySold >= 10)
{
    dblAmountTotalDue -= dblQuantitySold * dblPrice * 0.05;
    MessageBox.Show("A 5% discount will be given because 10 or more has been sold.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead. Add additional conditional operator on your first if which will react as between two number condition.

```
if (dblQuantitySold >= 10 && dblQuantitySold < 20)
{
    dblAmountTotalDue -= dblQuantitySold * dblPrice * 0.05;
    MessageBox.Show("A 5% discount will be given because 10 or more has been sold.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (dblQuantitySold >= 20)
{
    dblAmountTotalDue -= dblQuantitySold * dblPrice * 0.10;
    MessageBox.Show("A 10% discount will be given because 20 or more has been sold.");
}
else if (dblQuantitySold >= 10)
{
    dblAmountTotalDue -= dblQuantitySold * dblPrice * 0.05;
    MessageBox.Show("A 5% discount will be given because 10 or more has been sold.");
}
```

Your conditions were in the wrong order.

If you want to go for bonus points try this code:

```
decimal price = 99;

decimal quantitySold = decimal.Parse(txtQuantity.Text);

var discounts = new[]
{
    new { percentage = 0.0m, threshold = 0 },
    new { percentage = 0.05m, threshold = 10 },
    new { percentage = 0.1m, threshold = 20 },
};

var discount =
    discounts
        .OrderBy(d => d.threshold)
        .Where(d => d.threshold <= quantitySold)
        .Last();

decimal amountTotalDue = quantitySold * price * (1m - discount.percentage);

if (discount.percentage > 0m)
{
    var message = String.Format(
        "A {0:0%}% discount will be given because {1} or more has been sold.",
        discount.percentage,
        discount.threshold)

    MessageBox.Show(message);
}

lblAmountDueTotal.Text = amountTotalDue.ToString("C");
```

The advantage here is that you separate the discount structure from the code that computes the discount. This allows you to then extract away the discounts into a file or database and allow the application to be easily customizable.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still fairly new to C#.